# Kivy app crashes after being packaged with pyinstaller due to window issue

Tags: kivy, pyinstaller

I'm trying to package my kivy project with Pyinstaller but it crashes and spits this out

```
[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window     provider at all!
sdl2 - Exception: SDL2: Unable to load image
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 67, in core_select_lib
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 138, in __init__
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 722, in __init__
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 255, in   
 create_window

 File "site-packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 897, in create_window
 File "kivy\graphics\instructions.pyx", line 756, in     
 kivy.graphics.instructions.RenderContext.__init__ (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:10729)
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 512, in __init__
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 700, in _set_filename
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 430, in load
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\__init__.py", line 198, in __init__
 File "site-packages\kivy\core\image\img_sdl2.py", line 42, in load

[INFO              ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 513, in __get__
File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
Exception ignored in: 'kivy.properties.dpi2px'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "site-packages\kivy\utils.py", line 513, in __get__
File "site-packages\kivy\metrics.py", line 175, in dpi
File "site-packages\kivy\base.py", line 126, in ensure_window
SystemExit: 1
[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I did not create my own spec file I chose to do it via the command line by passing the required arguments any suggestions?

This is the spec file generated by pyinstaller

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['apv.py'],
         pathex=['C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy', 'C:\\Python34', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Users\\suroh\\Desktop\\my-python-modules', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\deps', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\site-packages\\kivy\\graphic', 'C:\\Python34\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python34\\libs', 'C:\\Python34\\Scripts', 'C:\\Python34\\share\\sdl2\\bin', 'C:\\Python34\\share\\glew\\bin', 'C:\\Python34\\share', 'C:\\Python34\\Tools', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\ctypes', 'C:\\Python34\\Lib\\distutils', 'C:\\Users\\suroh\\Desktop\\Python Projects\\testp\\Beta 01'],
         binaries=None,
         datas=None,
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=['pygame'],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='apv',
      debug=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=False , icon='LauncherIcon.ico')
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           name='apv')
```

Comment: Please add spec file. I think you probably didn't add deps to the spec, because `Unable to load image` wants some file from sdl2 folder(at least in errors I experienced).

Comment: As I said I didn't use my own spec file, pyinstaller did generate it's own so I'll put that up I guess.

Comment: You may try install pygame first. Please refer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24865559/unable-to-get-a-window-abort-kivy-error-when-running-an-executable-compiled-fr

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't create spec file, you still *need* to package the dependencies which are [here](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html#packaging-a-simple-app) in the `Collect()`.

As it is mentioned in the pyinstaller's [docs](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/operating-mode.html#analysis-finding-the-files-your-program-needs):

> You can give additional files on the pyinstaller command line.

Which means that you could do [`--add-data`](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#what-to-bundle-where-to-search) or you can dump the spec somewhere and edit it manually with [`--specpath`](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#what-to-generate). [Here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/blob/65dcf9a3cb46926b26bc5934fe375b5336f074b8/PyInstaller/building/api.py#L595) is what `Collect()` basically does to package the stuff.

**Edit:**
Yup, you're definitely missing the deps. Look at kivy's spec.

If you would go for `--add-data`, you should check `kivy.deps` folder and `__init__()`s in them, because those will tell you what path you are looking for. But editing the spec manually is less time consuming.

Comment: Thanks mate this is the clearest answer I've found on this I can't believe I missed it but still thank you because it was a massive pain!